How do you use a windows application that starts in the windows system tray with wine?
I'm trying to use a windows app called negative screen. I think I can get it to run but I'm not sure what to do from there because this app isn't supposed to start a window on it's own on launch and I don't see it in the linux system tray either. I've tried running it in the terminal too but that didn't work either
mainly I tried it in lutris.
What do I have to do to be able to use this on linux?
I'm also curious as to whether or not apps like this exist on linux, I couldn't find any myself. Any way to invert the color of my screen
or shift the hue is what I'm really looking for. xcalib doesn't let me invert the brightness on it's own so that's out too. Also I'm on wayland.

I think Wayland does not support "AppIndicators", but you can try the https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/7332/status-icons/ GNOME extension.

Ubuntu 24.04 (from 18.04) with GNOME desktop environment has a Night Light feature included by default. Night Light works with both X11 and Wayland. To enable Night Light System Settings -> Screen Display -> Night Light and slide the Night Light slider from OFF to ON. Then configure the schedule settings.

There are some linux products that are similar. Take a look at the following link: -
https://alternativeto.net/software/negativescreen/
Details of f.flux: -
https://justgetflux.com/
To add f.lux I found the following link:-
https://dev.to/benjaminspak/save-your-eyes-how-to-install-flux-on-ubuntu-4fl1
(Last edited June/2020)
But note: I have not installed this myself so I don't know even if it will install on 24.04 (You don't mention which OS you are using.) (I have read (after writing this) that it has been broken for a while (May 2024). If you do get it working successfully I could add the install instructions here.
I have found a snap version that looks current which might be a better option: -
https://snapcraft.io/install/fluxgui/ubuntu
But X11 only - not Wayland

For running a WINE program try to install using PlayOnLinux which you can install first. This makes installation of programs a lot easier than doing it by hand. It also gives you an interface so you can run a program from a desktop icon. Warning - installing under WINE can be troublesome to get going.
Good Luck
